# Random 3's are filling my pin field and it's telling me to enter a pin that is not mine

Tags: windows, windows-10

My Win 10 64 bit pro is telling me to enter a specific code to gain access to my desktop anyone come across this?
I really don't want to reset my PC I have recording/video  software that takes forever to install 
I use bitdefender, 
Malwarebytes
Free firewall version 1.49
Any help would be greatly appreciated
~AC~

Answer (score 1):

If you enter the PIN incorrectly several times it will block any further attempts until you enter a specific string of characters that it displays on screen.

Source? My kids hammer my keyboard all day, every day. I deal with this all the time.

As for the random 3s? Perhaps you have a sticky key?